# How to fetch matching values from a dictionary object in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, dictionary

I have a dictionary object which is populated as follows:

```
const myDictionaryElement = this.myDictionary["abc"];
```

Here, `myDictionaryElement` has the values:

```
ACheckStatus: "PASS"
QVVStatus: "READY"
VVQStatus: "READY"
QTTStatus: "READY"
QBCTTStatus: "READY"
CStatus: "FAIL"
```

I want to create a object such that all `key-value` pairs for which the key has matching `VV` in the middle should be stored in object `valuesVV` as following:

```
const valuesVV = { QVVStatus: "READY" };
```

Similary all `key-value` pairs for which the key has matching `TT` in the middle should be stored in object `valuesTT` as following:

```
const valuesTT = { QTTStatus: "READY", QBCTTStatus: "READY" } ;
```

And all `key-value` pairs for which the key doesn't have matching `VV` and `TT` in the middle should be stored in object `valuesOther` as following:

```
const valuesOther = { ACheckStatus: "PASS", VVQStatus: "READY", CStatus: "FAIL"  } ;
```

To achieve the about output, I am using `hasOwnProperty` for dictionary but it is not working

```
const valuesVV = myDictionaryElement.hasOwnProperty('*VV*');  // It is returning boolean false. The desired output is { QVVStatus: "READY" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generalize it by creating a function that takes the dict and a matches array like the following:

```
const dict = {
  ACheckStatus: "PASS",
  QVVStatus: "READY",
  VVQStatus: "READY",
  QTTStatus: "READY",
  QBCTTStatus: "READY",
  CStatus: "FAIL"
};

const matching = ['VV', 'TT', 'SS'];

function matchInput(input, matches) {
  // will have matched object in the index of the match and those without a match 
  // at the end
  const res = [];

  Object.keys(input).forEach(key => {
    // flag if the key wasn't matched to add it to no matches object
    let matched = false;

    matches.forEach((match, i) => {
      if (key.indexOf(match) > 0) {
        matched = true;
        if (!res[i]) res[i] = {};
        res[i][key] = input[key];
      }
    });

    if (!matched) {
      if (!res[matches.length]) res[matches.length] = {};
      res[matches.length][key] = input[key];
    }
  });

  return res;
}
```

The idea is to go over each key and insert it in the right bucket (object)

Answer (score 1):

You should filter the object keys and select only the ones you need, then use reduce to create a new object:

```
 const vvItems = Object.keys(dictElement)
  .filter(key => key.indexOf('VV')>= 1)
  .reduce((o, key) => { o[key] = dictElement[key]; return o; }, {})
```

Comment: I think this is going to include `{ QVVStatus: "READY" }` and `VVQStatus: "READY"` However, I want only `{ QVVStatus: "READY" }`. The one where `VV` falls in the middle

Comment: @meallhour You can use `indexOf('VV') > 1` so that it will skip strings that starts with `VV`. Updated the answer

Comment: In your answer, you have `indexOf('VV') >= 1` Should it be `indexOf('VV') > 1`?

Comment: It is working and I am able to get values for `valuesVV ` and `valuesTT` But how to include the `Not condition` here to get `valuesOther` Something like `! (indexOf('VV') && ! (indexOf('TT')> 1)`